# Howto add content to Response?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, jax-ws, response

My WebService (I want to put the uuid string in the response)

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createObject(final String jsonString) {
    String uuid;
    //logic
    ...
    String mt = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(uuid);
    return Response.ok(uuid, mt).build();
    //also tried: Response.status(200).entity(uuid).build();
}
```

My Request (reading the uuid from response)

```
Response response = target.request().post(Entity.entity(new Gson().toJson(params, Map.class), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
response.getEntity() //returns null if i access it
```

The entity is always null when i try to access it. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to return a `Response` object? You can simply return a `String`. `public String createObject(..) {..return UUIDString;}`

Comment: When i return the String it works but i would like also to check the http (error) status codes on client side

Comment: Try to return only one entity i.e. `return Response.ok(uuid).build();`

Comment: Tried but same Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i found the problem:

It was a parsing Problem, somehow i always got null until i changed my request code from

```
response.getEntity()
```

to this:

```
String uuid = new Gson().fromJson(response.readEntity(String.class), String.class);
```